# Where to put a function in Qt Quick with C++ to be called over and over again as the main code runs?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, infinite-loop

I'm learning Qt Quick qml but I have problems with the main loop.

I have two functions called `update()` (for variety of things) and `fixedUpdate()` (for handling physics) and I'm wondering where to put them in order to be called repeatedly.

I'm not sure what function or section of the code in Qt Quick is for this operation. (I only know that exec() contains main loop but that is inaccessible. Only with some functions and qml arguments/objects like onClicked etc.)

This is my rough **example of C++ code without utilizing qml** when I know how to do it:

```qml
int Engine::run()
{
    // Do some init here

    while (true)
    {
        // Update deltaTime here

        if (event_quit)
            break;

        if (time_to_update)
        {
            // Reset time_to_update
            fixedUpdate();
        }

        update();

        // End frame here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using things like `Q_PROPERTY` and `signals:` for handling variable changes but I'm unable to find which function or event handler is used for functions which have to be called forever as long as the program runs.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: you need a [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html), but i am not a qml expert, so i cannot tell you how to integrate it into your (not shown) code.

Comment: Maybe the [Timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-timer.html) would be sufficient, but it seems better to handle this outside of QML, as the `Timer` does not accept a 0 interval.

Comment: qml is multithreaded (i.e. changing every object may activate another thread), one should be careful with global frame updates...

Comment: @AhmedAEK (I forgot how to edit comments so I lost everything what I wrote and now I don't know what I wanted to say. Nevermind.) In Unity Engine they have function called Update(). This function is called over and over again as fast as you CPU allows it. I'm trying to make my own Update() function which I know how to use in bare C++. I just need to place it in endless loop. But in QML combined with C++? I'm clueless.

Comment: @AhmedAEK .. The only endless loop is in exec() where things like onClicked are checked.  (and I think that onClicked wouldn't work without a loop). I just don't know what can I do to make Qt call my function at the same rate for example as onClicked.

Comment: unity is immediate mode GUI while QT is retained, don't expect the same code to work, specifically you can't have infinite loops in retained mode GUI, the way you implement a similar functionality in retained mode GUI is through a custom signal, this signal will have your `update()` function connected to it, and at the end of the `update()` method you emit the signal again (therefore pushing a message to the event queue to re-run the update function later), the first emit of the signal must happen from something like a showEvent of the window.

Comment: The implication of your question is disastrous because it doesn't respect the need to allow idle time to allow your thread and other threads to catch up on work. Had you mentioned anything where you are making your task thread-safe, and/or, blocking on an event, then, your question may be treated with a different level of appreciation. The question also lacks consideration of existing QML components that support particle physics which had you considered them, you would not had to worry about (1) a thread blocking loop, (2) thread safety. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-effects-particles.html